# pytesseract can't recognise digits from a image,

Tags: python, python-tesseract, digits

The image I'm trying to analyze is the following:

[image]

I'm running this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

my_image = 'C:\\autobot_wwe_supercard\\imagenes\\codigo_arriba.png'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(my_image))

print(text)
```

The result that is giving me is:

[image]

I have installed pytesseract by console with pip install pytesseract.

Comment: your picture is nice and clean. Tesseract will give correct output. just try inverting the image begore passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> img = cv2.imread("1299.png")
>>> gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
>>> thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
>>> thresh = 255 - thresh
>>> data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config='--psm 11 digits')
>>> data
'1299'
>>>
```

Try whitelisting digits in the configuration.
*pytesseract* is capable of extracting white text on black background too sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

pytesseract is not the best choice. Try to put some padding around text when you crop the region of interest.

Comment: instead of pytesseract what would you recomend?. I'm stuck with trying to extract that number. And how do I put some padding?